# Azure Create AD App with AllowImplicit user is not albe to login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

i am trying to create a azure ad app and set client id in that app, but some how i am not able to login in that app throwing me error like "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbE0f.png)

i've set all the required delegate permission to that app 
 [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsM7I.png)

i've set "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" this permission also 
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7px4W.png)

if some one can help it will be great help

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

The [Registered app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) you have created need to support personal account. Please make sure the option ***Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*** is selected while creating an app as below image

[image]

Comment: Hello Hari Krishna thanks for your answer but i've already set that permission too while creating that app. Please let me know if any other settings i am missing

Comment: Hi @JackKD, There will be one more case where we are trying to log in with V1 end point. Since V1 is not supported for personal accounts it will give us issues. We need t use V2 end point to fix this issue. Reference document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

Comment: Please let me know if you still need any help.

Comment: Hi @Hari ,i am refering v2.0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2Fuser_impersonation%20openid%20profile&client_id=77bf7f40-92e7-4a01-8db8-f3022a5e8fa4&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=eyJpZCI6IjQ0NzdlZTY3LThlNzItNGVhZC04NmUyLTcyM2ZlODY5ZGY4OCIsInRzIjoxNTkyMzk5MjU3LCJtZXRob2QiOiJwb3B1cEludGVyYWN0aW9uIn0%3D&nonce=145afcc9-c791-47d5-a4e6-d22e4cf110cd&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.3.2&client-request-id=99227eca-24a7-461e-a53a-58f4db0f58cd&response_mode=fragment"

Comment: Please refer the URL mention i am hitting same url but not able to login with outlook users!!!

Comment: /organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F%2Fuser_impersonation&client_id=77bf7f40-92e7-4a01-8db8-f3022a5e8fa4&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=eyJpZCI6IjA4YzM3OTJmLWViMDItNDVmNC04ZTEyLTg3Y2QzZDYyNmQ2MSIsInRzIjoxNTkyNDAzMjc4LCJtZXRob2QiOiJwb3B1cEludGVyYWN0aW9uIn0%3D&nonce=008bdb6e-721a-4c8b-85da-45bc6f2b4265&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.3.2&client-request-id=c9387f8c-51fa-47fe-aaf2-2d119b769b3f&response_mode=fragment&sso_reload=true

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com domain is this but still not allowing user for outlook

Comment: I am sorry you need to use common only. The problem is with the scope and not the end point. Please try below url

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20&client_id=77bf7f40-92e7-4a01-8db8-f3022a5e8fa4&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=eyJpZCI6IjA4YzM3OTJmLWViMDItNDVmNC04ZTEyLTg3Y2QzZDYyNmQ2MSIsInRzIjoxNTkyNDAzMjc4LCJtZXRob2QiOiJwb3B1cEludGVyYWN0aW9uIn0%3D&nonce=008bdb6e-721a-4c8b-85da-45bc6f2b4265&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.3.2&client-request-id=c9387f8c-51fa-47fe-aaf2-2d119b769b3f&response_mode=fragment&sso_reload=true

Comment: I have removed https://management.core.windows.net//user_impersonation in your scope as it is not correct

Comment: please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I needed  "scp": "user_impersonation" this in my access token so i need to pass "management.core.windows.net//user_impersonation" this in my url, is there any way to get "user_impersonation" in my access token??

Comment: The api which you are using i.e., `management.core.windows.net//user_impersonation` has no permission for personal accounts to access it.

Comment: so how can i allow permission to this scope "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/servers/createorupdate#code-try-0" when i hit this url and click on Try It ,it ask me to login and then it redirects to login then it returns with a token at end of page after login so how the scope is add to that access token??

Comment: With personal accounts you can't as it is only accessible with v1 endpoint