# Graph API azure directory authorization error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a graph API app and want it to be accessible to every user for authorizing.

The app is made to be a multi-tenant application that should be available to everyone (see screenshot)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nk3K.png).

When a user who is not added to the azure active directory tries to access to grant permissions to the app, they get this error saying "the user is not added to the azure active directory, and the user needs to be added as a tenant  to the app"

I am using this link for oauth access https://login.microsoftonline.com/DIRECTORY_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID2&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access Channel.Create Channel.ReadBasic.All ChannelMessage.Send Team.ReadBasic.All Group.ReadWrite.All&state=12345

[error message from graph app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEZaY.png)

Comment: Hi @Pallavi, please mention the question here with clear details.

Comment: Hello @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I have edited the description with more details

Comment: Hi @Pallavi, I have corrected the URL from  application id to directory id in your question. I will update the answer for your scenario soon.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a tenant specific endpoint which will not  support personal account. You need to use a `common` endpoint(`login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/`).

Based on your URL you have shared, you can use below example syntax,

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID2&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access
```

Also, Please refer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412798/azure-create-ad-app-with-allowimplicit-user-is-not-albe-to-login/62413949#62413949).